# What is the appropriate way to store Firebase Authentication info so you can leave the app and come back still signed in?

Tags: swiftui, firebase-authentication

I followed a few examples online and now have a `SessionData` class that stores auth details, etc. When you fill out fields for email and password on the login screen, it updates the email and password in `SessionData` and then uses that to authenticate with Firebase. I have authentication working fine, but I can't figure out how to store authentication locally on the device so people don't have to sign-in again if they leave the app. The example I found shows @AppStorage for the `logged_in` status, but I've read that @AppStorage should not be used for usernames and passwords due to security issues. Any thoughts?

```
class SessionData : ObservableObject {
    @Published var remember = true
    @Published var email = ""
    @Published var password = ""
    @Published var isSignUp = false
    @Published var email_SignUp = ""
    @Published var password_SignUp = ""
    @Published var confirmPassword = ""
    @Published var isLinkSend = false
    @Published var alert = false
    @Published var alertMsg = ""
    @AppStorage("log_Status") var logged_in = false
    @Published var isLoading = false

    func login(){
        
        // checking all fields are inputted correctly...
        
        if email == "" || password == ""{
            
            self.alertMsg = "Please enter email and password!"
            self.alert.toggle()
            return
        }
        
        withAnimation{
            
            self.isLoading.toggle()
        }
        
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, err) in
        ...
...
}
```

Comment: Firebase already stores the sign-in information and tries to restore it when the user restarts the app. To pick up this authentication state, use an auth state listener as shown in the first snippet on: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Answer (score 1):

Ah, of course I figured it out right after posting. I wanted to leave this here since I couldn't find this asked anywhere.

Link: https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess

It's a great Keychain access wrapper that makes it *very* simple to store/retrieve data securely.

Comment: This is actually not needed. Firebase already stores the sign-in information and tries to restore it when the user restarts the app. To pick up this authentication state, use an auth state listener as shown in the first snippet on: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user